# How to make animated box?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How do I create an effect like the following URL:
https://www.tinkapp.com/en/

[image]

After mousing over the "box", the three lines animate to be like:

[image]

After moving the mouse outside of the box, the lines come back together again. How can I replicate this effect?

Comment: use hover pseudo to change the image

Comment: The lines "animate" to get further aparent, it does not look like just "2 images" with one close, and one apart. It seems like the three lines are drawn/dom instead of image, am not fully sure.

Comment: You already have the code. Inspect the element in that page and learn to replicate it.

Comment: I dont know what code there is specific to this, it looks like theres  a "menu-opener" div that uses some javascript? Not many dom elements, was guessing the lines are made from borders? or hr's. Not clear to me. A CSS3 only way is best.

Comment: if it's a element it's probably like <div><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p></div>! or unordered list Then you just change line height in hover.

Comment: @Rolando - The JavaScript has nothing to do with the `hover`. Just use your browsers dev tools. The lines are made with a `span` using pseudo `:before` and `:after` elements. They have an absolute position where on `hover` the `top` position gets transitioned. That's all.

Comment: create your own template for it and play with it. If you want animation use transition or animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, a more elegant and flexible solution would be using Flexboxes. You can then simply change the margin for the horizontal lines on hover. Add a `transition` property to the non-hovered rule to make it animate nicely.

Markup:

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

*relevant* CSS:

```
.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.line {
  transition: margin 0.3s;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.hamburger:hover .line {
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

[Full CSS&HTML with style on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqMPGe)

I prefer this over the `transform` solution posted previously as this one doesn't require code duplication and I find it more declarative. You want the lines to move apart, not the first line to go up and the third line to go down.

As for browser support, both are similar - see [2D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) vs [Flexboxes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/).

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightBlue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: white;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
.hamburger:hover .line {
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS approach to create the transition effect required with `tranform` property.

Target the 1st and 3rd line with `:nth-child` and apply the `translateY` property value. `transition` property can provide you the ease effect just like in the page you mentioned.

**Edit:** Added margin property for older browser support

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4AC6B7;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.line {
  width: 20px;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
.box:hover > .line:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  /* margin-top: -5px; For transform fallback */
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}
.box:hover > .line:nth-child(2) {
  /* margin-top: 15px; When not using transform */
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}
.box:hover > .line:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  /* margin-top: 15px; For transform fallback */
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```